# Split a large matrix every N columns?

Tags: r, matrix, split

Does anyone know of an elegant way to split a matrix every N columns? It's a large matrix so I don't want to convert it into a datatable and I'd like to use base R.

Comment: Can you please give more details. How do you want to retrieve the matrix parts?

Comment: I have a numerical matrix with about 10,000 columns. I'd like to end up with a list of submatrices that each have 100 columns. Since it's such a large object I don't want to go through a dataframe intermediate.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply` :

```
N <- 2
list_mat <- lapply(seq_len(ncol(mat)/N) - 1, function(x) 
                   mat[,(N * x + 1) : (N * x+2)])
list_mat
#[[1]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1   11
# [2,]    2   12
# [3,]    3   13
# [4,]    4   14
# [5,]    5   15
# [6,]    6   16
# [7,]    7   17
# [8,]    8   18
# [9,]    9   19
#[10,]   10   20

#[[2]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   21   31
# [2,]   22   32
# [3,]   23   33
# [4,]   24   34
#...
```

This works directly because you have 10,000 (`ncol`) columns and want divide them in 100 (`N`) columns each. i.e `ncol` is completely divisible by `N`.

**data**

```
mat <- matrix(1:100, ncol = 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
mout <- Map(as.matrix,split.default(as.data.frame(m),ceiling(seq(ncol(m))/N)))
```

**Example**

```
> mout
$`1`
     V1 V2 V3 V4
[1,]  4  1 23 18
[2,] 39 34 14 33

$`2`
     V5 V6 V7 V8
[1,] 21 10 35  7
[2,] 32 22 30  9

$`3`
     V9 V10 V11 V12
[1,] 15   5  28  19
[2,] 31  25  29   2

$`4`
     V13 V14 V15 V16
[1,]  27  36  38   3
[2,]  20  12  40   6

$`5`
     V17 V18 V19 V20
[1,]  17  24  37  16
[2,]   8  11  26  13
```

**DATA**

```
set.seed(1)
m <- matrix(sample(40),ncol = 20)
N <- 4
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `gl` to create an index for `split`ting

```
lapply(split(seq_len(ncol(mat)), as.integer(gl(ncol(mat), 2, ncol(mat)))),
       function(i) mat[,i])
```

#### data

```
mat <- matrix(1:100, ncol = 10)
```